# Como crear la estructura de un Json a un Array de PHP

Tags: php, json

Buenos días tengo un Json pero estoy intentando pasar el Json a estructura de un Array de PHP.
Espero que me puedan a apoyar.
Les comparto el Json que intento pasar a estructura de Array

> Código Json

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID_CDR": "1416",
      "RFC_CRM": "XAX010101000"
    },
    {
      "ID_CDR": "1417",
      "RFC_CRM": "XEX010101000"
    }
  ],
  "result": {
    "fields": [
      "ID_CDR",
      "RFC_CRM"
    ],
    "message": true,
    "tasks": true
  }
}
```

Espero que me puedan orientar.

Saludos y excelente día.

Comment: ¿Qué intentas hacer con dicha estructura una vez convertida?, nos compartes que has intentado?

Comment: Estoy consumiendo una api que recibe una respuesta en Json, primero hice la prueba en postman y ya me hace la conecion y si se insertan el Json que mostré en el código, pero primero quiero crear el array para después convertirlo con a Json con json_encode y finalmente enviárselo a la api. Enseguida te comparto código de mi intento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes emplear `json_decode($stringJson)` para convertir el JSON a un array de PHP. Después puedes ver la estructura del array para saber cómo acceder a él con un temporal `die(print_r($myNewArray))` tras el `json_decode`.

También puedes convertir el array de PHP a JSON con la función `json_encode($phpArray)`.

Puedes ver las diferentes opciones de estas funciones en [la página del manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/index.php).